# Add more wrinkles to cloth

Tags: modeling, physics

I have some problems getting the tablecloth to be the way it should.

The issues I have are mainly tension and not enough wrinkles.

Since the cloth doesn't have enough tension, the part marked with red is not stretched and does not look like it does in the concept art. I tried decreasing the mass of the cloth so it doesn't pull it down that much but it doesn't really change much.

What the cloth doesn't have as well are enough wrinkles. In the concept art, there are wrinkles across the edge that I can't seem to replicate. Increasing the bending just makes it unnaturally bendy without adding any more wrinkles to it.

How can I make the cloth look more realistic and more like in the concept art?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Add some object underneath the cloth that have the rough structure of the wrinkles you need. Then re-do the cloth simulation.

Comment: This generally requires a higher resolution mesh, a better quality simulation, and hence longer baking time. The fabric may also need to be stiffer and require some sort of additional motion that forces the creation of wrinkles.

Comment: since it appears you are making a still, you could also apply the cloth simulation and sculpt in the wrinkles you want. nice render.

Comment: @ChrisHowe thanks! I've also come to the realization that the concept art might look real, but in a physical simulation the cloth would look much different.